# User change value in the array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, methods

I am new to C# for the last hour i was trying to find a tutorial how to provide 
a way for the user to change the value of  any element in the array and it needs to make sure that the index is valid. Can you help me or provide me the info so I can learn it. I can't seem to find it at least nothing simple since I am still new to programming.

Code sample provided below which I will work with.

Clarify: User inputs value switch it out with one of the index value they choose.

```
 int[] A = { -2, 5, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 };//<<< values
 ChangedArray(A);

 //Method down here returning value on top to display array
 static void ChangeArray(int[] array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n=============\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", array[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n=============\n");
    }
```

Comment: How are you detecting which value the user wants to change? And what value they want to use?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here.  Are you asking how to receive user input?  How to set a value?  Have you tried something and received an error or observed unexpected behavior?

Comment: Receive user input and then switch which ever index they choose and switch out the value of that index with user input.

Comment: Your calling function name and actual function name is different.and please clerify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assume valid user input.

You can index the array and then simply assign the value

```
 static void ChangeArray(int[] array)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int newValue= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if(index <= array.Length && index >= 0)
    {
        array[index] = newValue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n=============\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}", array[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n=============\n");
}
```

Comment: @TheBoringGuy haha sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
public void Main(...)
{
    Try 
    {
        int[] myArray = { -2, 5, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 };
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
        int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
        ChangeArray(myArray,index, newValue);
    }
    Catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

static void ChangeArray(int[] array, int index, int newValue )
    {
        if (array.Length >= index || index < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n=====No change========\n");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n=====Old values========\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            Console.Write("{0}", array[i]);

        array[index] = newValue;

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n======New values=======\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            Console.Write("{0}", array[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes valid input form the console and an `int[] A` in scope. I'm assuming that's where you want it from because your using Console methods otherwise.

```
  Console.Write("Index to edit:"); 
  int indexToChange = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.Write("To value:"); 
  int valueToSave = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
  A[indexToChange] = valueToSave;
```